# How to format data from axios request using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, strapi

I am calling Strapi API endpoint: get('/articles') to get an array of articles.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API,
});

class APIClient<T> {
  ...
  getAll = () => {
    return axiosInstance.get<T[]>(this.endpoint).then((res) => res.data);
  };
  ...
```

T is a generic type, in this case Article interface is passed: `new APIClient<Article>("/articles")`

Response scheme is:

```
Object {
   data: Object {
      data: [] <- Array of Articles
```

How do I format the data to get the array of Articles inside that Object?

- res.data returns an Object
- I also tried to destructure the data as shown here https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/integrations/react#example-1:
  `return axiosInstance.get<T[]>(this.endpoint).then(({ data }) => data.data)` but it gives an error: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'T[]'.

Any idea how can I solve this? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to bind the http response to an Article class ? Why you can't use the plain JavaScript object?

Comment: Yes, I want to tell typescript that axios.get method returns an array of Article Interface, not sure what you mean, Im trying to use type annotation

Comment: Share us your Article Interface or a minimal reproducible sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By creating an additional interface to match the response** I was able to solve the problem and maintain type annotation:

```
interface ApiResponse<T> {
   data: T
}
```

and then adding it to axios.get I was **able to access the 2nd data property** to return an array of Articles instead of an Object:

```
return axiosInstance
      .get<ApiResponse<T[]>>(this.endpoint)
      .then((res) => res.data.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are showing is the Typescript error, not the actual error that server returns.

The fastest way would be just replace `<T[]>` with `<any>` and figure out the proper type later.

Comment: Yes, that is a typescript error. The request is working fine, its a matter of accessing data. If I replace it with any I would not be using type annotation, or removing the return type on get while destructuring data also works : `return axiosInstance.get(this.endpoint).then(({ data }) => data.data)` but I would like to see if I could make it work with type annotation